# How to make the aftername start with the final letter of the beforename with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't answer this question, can someone help me please?

Take the following selection of 70
English Pokemon names, and generate
the sequence with the highest possible number of Pokemon names where the
subsequent name starts with the final letter of the preceding name. No Pokemon
name is to be repeated.

```
const pokemonList=['audino', 'bagon', 'baltoy', 'banette', 'bidoof', 'braviary', 'bronzor', 'carracosta', 'charmeleon', 'cresselia', 'croagunk', 'darmanitan', 'deino', 'emboar', 'emolga', 'exeggcute', 'gabite', 'girafarig', 'gulpin', 'haxorus', 'heatmor', 'heatran', 'ivysaur', 'jellicent', 'jumpluff', 'kangaskhan', 'kricketune', 'landorus', 'ledyba', 'loudred', 'lumineon', 'lunatone', 'machamp', 'magnezone', 'mamoswine', 'nosepass', 'petilil', 'pidgeotto', 'pikachu', 'pinsir', 'poliwrath', 'poochyena', 'porygon2', 'porygonz', 'registeel', 'relicanth', 'remoraid', 'rufflet', 'sableye', 'scolipede', 'scrafty', 'seaking', 'sealeo', 'silcoon', 'simisear', 'snivy', 'snorlax', 'spoink', 'starly', 'tirtouga', 'trapinch', 'treecko', 'tyrogue', 'vigoroth', 'vulpix', 'wailord', 'wartortle', 'whismur', 'wingull', 'yamask'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformulate the problem to finding the longest path in a directed graph.
Building the graph: connect (edge) word x to word y if word y starts with the same letter as the last letter of word x.

Comment: I understand but not sure how to do it with code :(

Comment: which part? building the graph? or finding the longest path?

Comment: Building the graph